# Using sed, how to print all lines that match a certain date?

Tags: grep, sed, text-editing

Using sed, how to print all lines where the birthdays are in November or December?

Assuming input file name "datebook" as follows:

```
Steve Blenheim:238-923-7366:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:20300
Betty Boop:245-836-8357:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:14500
Igor Chevsky:385-375-8395:3567 Populus Place, Caldwell, NJ 23875:6/18/68:23400
Karen Evich:284-758-2857:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:7/25/53:85100
Fred Fardbarkle:674-843-1385:20 Parak Lane, Duluth, MN 23850:4/12/23:780900
Lori Gortz:327-832-5728:3465 Mirlo Street, Peabody, MA 34756:10/2/65:35200
Paco Gutierrez:835-365-1284:454 Easy Street, Decatur, IL 75732:2/28/53:123500
Ephram Hardy:293-259-5395:235 CarltonLane, Joliet, IL 73858:8/12/20:56700
ABE LINCOLN:813-555-0123:1549 Cabin Drive, Springfield, IL 61801:2/12/09:79000
James Ikeda:834-938-8376:23445 Aster Ave., Allentown, NJ 83745:12/1/38:45000
```

Comment: Are the dates in M/D/Y or D/M/Y format?

Answer (score 5):

```
egrep '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:(11|12)/'
```

```
sed -rn '/^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:(11|12)\//p'
```

- `/regex/p` – print lines matching a regex
- `^` – beginning of line
- `[^:]+` – first, second, third fields (any number of any characters except `:`)
- `:` – field separators
- `(11|12)\/` – either `11` or `12`, followed by a `/`

```
awk -F: '$4 ~ /^(11|12)\//'
```

```
perl -aF: -ne 'print if $F[3] =~ /^(11|12)\//'
```

Comment: Could you please explain the sed command in details? how come we have so many [^:]+  ? Thank you

Comment: Could you please read a regexp tutorial? `[]`, `^`, `*` are explained in [many places](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX). thank you

Comment: Could have done shorter? I'd have written `^([^:]+:){3}(11|12)`, or even (looking at the format) `:(11|12)\/`.

Comment: or, anchor at the end: `/:1[12][^:]*:[^:]*$/`

Comment: Your side-by-side comparison demonstrates the advantages of a language that knows what a field is (awk and perl) versus ones that just see streams of characters (egrep and sed).

Comment: sed -rn '/^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:(11|12)\//p' => this works as expected. thank you Grawity

Answer (score 1):

Not sed, but grep is easier and more appropriate.

```
grep -E "(11|12)/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}" steve.txt
```

(11|12) means match either 11 or 12 and \d{1,2} means match 1 or 2 digits.